# Mocked method that raises exception has call count of 0 in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, patch

I'm trying to ensure that a call to a method happens and while mocking an exception being raised from that method, but it seems I can only do one at a time. When an exeception is raised, even if said exception is caught, the call count for the method which raised it is not incremented.

Technically, I don't have to check the call count, but I do so in the method's caller's other tests, so I wanted to repeat the pattern here.

I have not spotted anything in the patch documentation about exceptions interrupting the call count.

Code sample:

upload_service.py:

```py
class UploadService:
  # ...
  def upload(self):
    # ...
    try:
      gcs_blob = Blob(name, gcs_bucket)
      gcs_blob.upload_from_string(data=json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
    except GoogleCloudError as e:
      logging.exception("Error uploading file")
      # ...
```

test_upload_service.py:

```py
class TestUploadService(unittest.TestCase):
  # ...
  def test_upload_failure(self):
    us = UploadService(...)
    with patch("upload_service.Blob") as mocked_blob:
      gcs_blob = mocked_blob.return_value
      gcs_blob.upload_from_string.side_effect = GoogleCloudError("Google Cloud error")
      result = us.upload()
      self.assertEqual(1, mocked_blob.upload_from_string.call_count)
```

Expected result: the test passes.

Actual result:

```py
Ran 1 test in 0.021s

FAILED (failures=1)


0 != 1

Expected :1
Actual   :0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../test_upload_service.py", line 543, in test_upload_failure
    self.assertEqual(1, mocked_blob.upload_from_string.call_count)
AssertionError: 1 != 0
```

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there any documentation on call counting I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcs_blob` is an instance of `upload_service.Blob`, obtained by calling the class object, so a call to an instance method of `gsc_blob` should be asserted on the return value of `upload_service.Blob` instead of `upload_service.Blob` itself:

```
self.assertEqual(1, mocked_blob().upload_from_string.call_count)
```

or (since `gcs_blob = mocked_blob.return_value` in the test):

```
self.assertEqual(1, gcs_blob.upload_from_string.call_count)
```

Comment: That makes sense, figures I was missing something obvious.
I also patch `logging.exception` and check call counts in a similar manner as how I was trying to mock Blobs, but wasn't running into this error. In hindsight, that's because we log via static methods, rather than instantiating Logger objects (otherwise I'd probably see similar errors). Thanks for the insight!